# Webscrape incomplete after turning to DataFrame

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm webscraping from the table from this website https://www.iban.com/country-codes but when putting it into a DataFrame, the scraped information is incomplete.

```
# Webscrape list of official countries with country codes
url = 'https://www.iban.com/country-codes'
response = requests.get(url) 
page = response.content
scraping = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml") 
scraping
element = scraping.find("table", attrs={"class" : "table table-bordered downloads tablesorter"})
df = pd.read_html(str(element))
countrycodes = df[0]
```

so for example, countries like: Philippines (the), United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland (the), Switzerland were not part of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

The data are in the DataFrame. When you print `countrycodes` to the screen, `pandas` will shorten the dataframe and put `...` instead of rows.

To demonstrate, this code will load the table and save it to the CSV:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.iban.com/country-codes')[0]
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Produces this CSV (Highlighted are the `"Philippines (the)"`):

[image]

Comment: thanks! I found the issue already and have fixed it. It was in a different dataframe so when i merged these together, some countries were deleted :)